# Save picture of current screen to disk AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to add a button to my flash game (AS3) and on click it saves a picture of the current users whole screen and saves it to pictures/disk automatically, but I don't know how to do that, I know how to add the button to the UI and add a click event and all that, just need to know how to make it save a picture of the current screen to disk (doesn't have to be just the flash screen, can be the WHOLE screen of the users pc, either way works!)

Comment: just read this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33845494/3623547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on my way writing you the answer but I found this post have a better explaination: [Is it possible to capture the screen and save the image in actionscript 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027489/is-it-possible-to-capture-the-screen-and-save-the-image-in-actionscript-3)

"Yes, it's possible.

Draw some display object to a BitmapData (the stage, for example) and crop it if neccesary (the second param of BitmapData::draw will help you out here).

Then, convert the raw pixel data to JPEG or PNG using some encoder. I'm sure up to this point, this is what those tutorials will explain you how to do.

Now, the third step is different but simple enough. Instead of sending the image data to a server side script, use a FileReference object. Since Flash Player 10, it has a method called save, that prompts the user to save a file locally.

Since this is a desktop app, you could also make it an AIR app. This will give more direct access to the file system and other features, in case you need them."